# Different fields for different users (people or organizations)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a website which allows only people registration. Now I would like to add organizations registration.

The problem is that people and organizations have **some identical fields** and **some different fields** (e.g. organizations haven't got a surname or date of birth but may have other fields that people don't need).

Users **behavior is the same**. Only fields are different.

What is the best way to implement organizations registration?
Should I create a polymorphic association or there is a simpler/better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply create first step where people can choose usual or organization's registration, and render right form then

for validations use `:if => lambda { self.organization? }`  ( organization boolean field)